# Karate masking headers sensitive info in response

Tags: karate

I am trying to mask sensitive data like secrets in response & cookies
I tried implementing HttpLogModifier from sample Karate code, but did not work

Currently, I am using 0.9.6 version of karate-core
If I try to upgrade to 1.0.1 & above version, I am getting errors such as
import com.****.karate.Results
=======> results.getFailedMap() is not found
Sharing the code snippet below
Can you help me understand how to proceed further
Is there any other dependency I need to add ?

added below karate-config.js code snippet
`var LM = Java.type('********.logMasker'); karate.configure('logModifier', LM.INSTANCE);`

added below logMasker.java code
`
public class logMasker implements HttpLogModifier {

```
public static final HttpLogModifier INSTANCE = new logMasker();

private static final Logger LOGGER = new Logger(logMasker.class);

private static final Pattern APP_SECRET_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*secret\\s*=\\s*(?<Secret>\\w+),?.*", Pattern.MULTILINE);

private static final Pattern TICKET_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*token\\s*=\\s*(?<token>\\S+),?.*", Pattern.MULTILINE);

private static final Pattern TOKEN_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*ticket\":\"\\s*(?<ticket>\\S+)\",.*authId\":\"\\s*(?<auth>\\S+)\"", Pattern.MULTILINE);

@Override
public boolean enableForUri(String uri) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public String uri(String uri) {
    return uri;
}

@Override
public String header(String header, String value) {
    System.out.println("Inside header block");
    if (header.toLowerCase().contains("authorization")) {
        String appSecret = "secret";
        String token = "token";
        String ticket = "ticket";

        if(value != null){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String[] headers = value.split(",");
            for (String item : headers){
                if (item.contains(token)){
                    item = maskHeader(token,item);
                }
                if(item.contains(secret)){
                    item = maskHeader(secret,item);

                }
                if(item.contains(ticket)){
                    item = maskHeader(ticket,item);

                }
                sb.append(item+",");
            }
            value=sb.toString();
        }



        if ( value != null && value.toLowerCase().contains("basic")) {
            value = "Basic ******";
        }

        if ( value != null && value.toLowerCase().contains("bearer")) {
            value = "Bearer ******";
        }

        if ( value != null && value.toLowerCase().contains("key")) {
            value = "Key key=******";
        }
    }
    if(header.toLowerCase().contains("set-cookie") || header.toLowerCase().contains("cookie")){
        StringBuffer cookieBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String[] cookieHeders = value.split(";");
        for(String cookie : cookieHeders){
            String[] items = cookie.split("=");
            if(items[0].trim().equals("ticket") || items[0].trim().equals("ticket")){
                cookie=items[0]+"=*****";
            }
            cookieBuffer.append(cookie+";");
        }
        value = cookieBuffer.toString();
    }
    System.out.println("Masked header"+value);
    return value;
}

private String maskHeader(String tokenKey, String item) {
    System.out.println("Inside masking block");
    System.out.println("Before masking header"+item);
    if(item.contains("ticket")) {
        String tokenArray[] = item.split(":");
        if(tokenArray[0].equals(tokenKey)){
            item = tokenArray[0]+"=*****";
        }
    }
    else{
        String tokenArray[] = item.split("=");
        if(tokenArray[0].equals(tokenKey)){
            item = tokenArray[0]+"=*****";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Masked item"+item);
    return item;
}

@Override
public String request(String uri, String request) {
    System.out.println("Inside request block");

    if(request != null){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        if(request.contains("client_secret")){
            String[] items = request.split("&");
            for(String s : items){
                if(s.contains("client_secret")){
                    String[] item = s.split("=");
                    s = item[0]+"=*****";
                }
                sb.append(s+"&");
            }
            request = sb.toString();
        }
        request = request.replaceAll("(\\n?\\s*\"password\"\\s?:\\s?\")[^\\n\"]*(\",?\\n?)", "$1$2");
        request = request.replaceAll("(\\n?\\s*\"client_secret\"\\s?:\\s?\")[^\\n\"]*(\",?\\n?)", "$1$2");
        return request;
    }
    System.out.println("Masked request"+request);
    return request;
}

@Override
public String response(String uri, String response) {
    System.out.println("Inside response block");
    // you can use a regex and find and replace if needed
    if(response != null){
        response = response.replaceAll("(\\n?\\s*\"client_secret\"\\s?:\\s?\")[^\\n\"]*(\",?\\n?)", "$1$2");
        response = response.replaceAll("(\\n?\\s*\"ticket\"\\s?:\\s?\")[^\\n\"]*(\",?\\n?)", "$1$2");
        response = response.replaceAll("(\\n?\\s*\"access_token\"\\s?:\\s?\")[^\\n\"]*(\",?\\n?)", "$1$2");
        response = response.replaceAll("(\\n?\\s*\"password\"\\s?:\\s?\")[^\\n\"]*(\",?\\n?)", "$1$2");
        response = response.replaceAll(".*ticket\":\"\\s*(?<token>\\S+)\",.*authId\":\"\\s*(?<auth>\\S+)\"", "$1$2");
        response = response.replaceAll("(\\n?\\s*\"offlineTicket\"\\s?:\\s?\")[^\\n\"]*(\",?\\n?)", "$1$2");
        response = response.replaceAll(".*Ticket: \\s*(?<token>\\S+)", "$1$2");
        return response;
    }
    System.out.println("Masked response"+response);
    return response;
}
```

}`

Comment: first - we don't support old versions. no one has reported this yet - so my only suggestion is you look at the interface and figure out what you are missing: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/http/HttpLogModifier.java - if still stuck follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue